# React JS show and hide

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a register page for two types of users as tabs, so when I click one kind of user the other should be hidden and the clicked user tab should be displayed. I tried useState, and the hiding works but the desired user form is not rendered. I'm sure I'm missing something here.

```
const [customerForm, setCustomerForm] = useState(true);
const [feForm, setFEForm] = useState(false);

  const FEToggle = () =>{

    customerForm ?  setCustomerForm(false)  : setCustomerForm(true)
    feForm ? feForm(false): setFEForm(true)
    

  }

  const CTRToggle = () =>{

    feForm ?  setFEForm(false)  : setFEForm(true)
    customerForm ? setCustomerForm(false): setCustomerForm(true)
    

  }

  <button type="button"  onClick={() => {FEToggle()}}>
  <i className="fa fa-building" />
  Financial Enterprise
  </button>
  <button type="button"  onClick={() => {CTRToggle()}}>
  <i className="fa fa-user" />
  Customer
  </button>
```

Comment: If there are two forms and one of them is always visible you could simplify this to a single boolean state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `FEToggle` and `CTRToggle` method

```js
const FEToggle = () => {
  setCustomerForm(prev => !prev)
  setFEForm(prev => !prev)
}

const CTRToggle = () => {
  setCustomerForm(prev => !prev)
  setFEForm(prev => !prev)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
feForm ? feForm(false): setFEForm(true)
```

change to

```
feForm ? setFEForm(false): setFEForm(true)
```